# Attempt to set Waypoints scrollThrottle value causes undefined object error

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I've got jQuery Waypoints working fine, using the Inview shortcut.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //$.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 0;

    var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
        element: $('body > footer')[0],
        enter: function(direction) {
            $('body > header').css({
                bottom: 240,
                position: 'absolute'
            })
        },
        exited: function(direction) {
            $('body > header').css({
                bottom: 32,
                position: 'fixed'
            })
        }
    });

});
```

The page's header sits 32px above the bottom of the window in fixed position until the footer scrolls into view, at which point the header is made position absolute (the body is the positioning context) to give the effect of the emerging footer pushing the header up the page as it emerges.

Scrolling the footer away of the bottom reverses things.

Great, but it's a little jumpy so I wanted to play with the scroll throttle value.  But if I uncomment the line that attempts to set scrollThrottle, I get: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.waypoints.settings')

I'm probably being incredibly stupid somewhere, but can't see it.  Thanks.

Comment: What version of `waypoints` are you using? In the last version (v4) the option `scrollThrottle` doesn't exist...

Comment: I've also created a fiddle to reproduce your desired behavior : https://jsfiddle.net/3r1w0a0a/? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ah. That explains that then. I thought I was just being an idiot with my JavaScript. I wanted to reduce the throttle value to see if it fixed the jumpiness I outlined in my question.

Comment: @andreivictor the fiddle isn't working on my phone, but Waypoints is doing what I want. It was only the throttling I wanted to adjust as the effect I want has a little bit of lag.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, (props to @andreivictor), is that scrollThrottle was removed from Waypoints in version 4 and so of course is undefined.